# Origin of the chess term "checkmate"

Tags: etymology

An attack on a king is called "check", why is an attack that guarantees the capture of a king called check*mate*? What is the origin?

Comment: Good additional reference on [Chess History](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_chess#Early_history)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=checkmate):

> checkmate
>
> mid-14c., from O.Fr. eschec mat, from Arabic shah mat "the king died" (see check (n.)), which according to Barnhart is a misinterpretation of Persian mat "be astonished" as mata "to die," mat "he is dead." Hence Persian shah mat, the ultimate source of the word, would be literally "the king is left helpless, the king is stumped." As a verb, from late 14c.

Here is a [nicer description](http://www.word-origins.com/definition/check.html) from word-orgins.com

> Checkmate (14th c.) comes via Old French eschec mat from Persian shāh māt ‘the king is left helpless’ ... From the very specific chess sense there developed more general applications such as ‘attack’, ‘arrest’, ‘stop’, ‘restrict’, and ‘verify’. Among these in the 18th century was ‘token used as a counterfoil for verifying something, such as an amount’. As check this survives mainly in American English (as in ‘hat-check’)
>
> Check as in ‘pattern of squares’ (14th c.) is probably short for chequer, which in turn is a reduced form of exchequer, a word derived ultimately from Vulgar Latin *scaccus.

Comment: so check just means "king"?

Comment: Check comes from a Persian phrase 'shah' (king) where 'shah mata / shah mat' meant 'the king is dead' or 'the king is helpless'. I believe this is actually the Persian gameplay terminology over 1000 years ago before Europeans really caught onto it.

Comment: Interestingly, that became "scacco matto" in Italian... although *matto* means *mad* in Italian!

Comment: In Swedish, it's "schack matt", which is pretty close to the original. Cool. (Chess is actually called Schack, fwiw..)

Comment: I find the etymology at [word origins (the nicer description)](http://www.word-origins.com/definition/check.html) questionable because of the reference to Vulgar Latin. It says check < eschequier (Old French) < eschec < *scaccus (Vulgar Latin) < shah (Arabic) < shah (Persian). I don't know what scaccus means exactly (does the '*' means it is reconstructed but not extant?), but Vulgar Latin is the name of the colloquial Latin at the time of the Roman Empire ... did the game of chess even exist then, and were there borrowings from Arabic at that time?

Comment: how did a non-Romance language like Swedish use the same term?

Comment: @Mitch: Etymonline also refers to the Vulgar Latin in [the etymology of the word check](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=check) with the same * which, honestly I am unsure of the meaning myself. I'd been thinking it is some note of the pronunciation so I googled `scaccus pronounce` which oddly comes up with lots of VL references. The game certainly existed for a long time, I believe originating in India (though I've heard speculation about Egyptian variety) [Here's a link](http://www.aerobiologicalengineering.com/wxk116/Roman/BoardGames/latruncu.html) about the Roman style "Latrunculi"

Comment: Chess is somewhat special etymology-wise in that many languages have assimilated it in some form or another and it is very, very old.

Answer (score 2):

*Check* comes from Arabic "Sheikh"; *mate* comes from "mat". Together the two Arabic words mean the sheikh or master or even king is dead, which signifies the end of a game of chess.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe it comes from the Arabic shahu-ka mat, literally, 'your king is dead'. (Shah is king, the ka suffix means 'your', and as the previous commentators have said, 'mat' means 'died'.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. Can you find any on- or off-line sources to help it out a bit?